# htaccess redirect www.subdomain.domain.com to subdomain.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to get this working on a community site which launches tomorrow, the site has 7 subdomains for each community in the project.  Annoyingly the person running it has printed posters with:
www.subdomain.domain.com

My latest attempt to fix this through htaccess is:
    AddType x-httpd-php53 .php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Deadline is tight so any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting failed DNS lookups

Comment: Same error even without htaccess (DNS server configuration issue) ?

Comment: It was a DNS configuration error, I've added www.subdomain... as a record and instead I'm now getting a 404 error (using @anubhava 's answer below in .htaccess)

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache or an other browser (because you can have cache problem with 301 redirect)

Comment: Just tried in incognito and still no joy. I dont believe it's getting to the htaccess as I just added some garbage to it and it did not cause an internal error on www.sub.domain.com, only on sub.domain.com

Comment: It is certainly necessary to change your Apache domain configuration

Answer (score 1):

> redirect `www.subdomain.domain.com` to `subdomain.domain.com`

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: IMHO, www.subdomain.domain.com is not best practice.

Comment: This works perfect (after I added wildcard to virtual host).  This should be marked as the correct answer.  This will save me hundreds of support calls from people who won't listen no matter how many times I tell them to just use http://subdomain.domain.com !  I cannot tell you how many times idiots I work with think they have to have the www. before a domain because their outlook / Word wont convert it to a hyperlink without the www. at the front.  Finally a solution to idiot proof my sites.